# neo4j query to return node with collection item

Tags: collections, neo4j

I have some nodes in Neo4J database with array attribute. Something like:

```
Node (name = firstNode, array = [fist, second])
Node (name = secondNode, array = [second, third])
```

I want write query to return this combination:

```
name = firstNode, arrayItem = first
name = firstNode, arrayItem = second
name = secondNode, arrayItem = second
Name = secondNode, arrayItem = third
```

Anyone some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNWIND` is for splitting up an array into multiple lines:

```
match (n:MyLabel)
unwind n.array as ele
return n.name, ele
```

(This assumes your nodes have a `MyLabel` label.)